# Is there a way to update my Xcode project without having to recreate it every time I build from Unity?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build

When I build a Unity project for iOS I create an Xcode project.

After that I must:

- fix errors in the Xcode project.
- Configure the Xcode project.
- Build the Xcode project.

Is there a way to update my Xcode project without having to recreate it every time I build from Unity?

Comment: I'd look at why you need to fix errors or configure the Xcode project Unity creates. Fix whatever the problem is on the Unity side. The build process is fully scriptable. Whatever it is you can handle it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your xcode project in `[PostProcessBuild()]`. You change setting, run pod file or any thing you need for your project.